# Function Returning Value of Type I don't Want it to Return

Tags: c

For a problem at school, I need to convert a ASCII string of character digits to a decimal value. I wrote a function to do this and specified the return type to be an *unsigned short* as you can see in the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned short str_2_dec(char* input_string, int numel);
int main()
{
  short input;
  char input_string[6]= "65535";

  input = str_2_dec(input_string, 5);

  printf("Final Value: %d", input);
  return 0;
}
unsigned short str_2_dec(char* input_string, int numel)
{
  int factor = 1;
  unsigned short value = 0;
  int index;

  for(index=0; index <(numel-1); index++)
  {
    factor *= 10;
  }

  for(index = numel; index > 0; index--)
  {
    printf("Digit: %d; Factor: %d; ", *(input_string+(numel-index))-48, factor);
    value += factor * ((*(input_string+(numel - index))-48));

    printf("value: %d\n\n", value);

    factor /= 10;
  }
  return value;
}
```

When running this code, the program prints `-1` as the final value instead of `65535`. It seems it's displaying the corresponding signed value anyway.  Seems like something very simple, but I can't find an answer. A response would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are taking the `unsigned short` return value of the function and storing it in a (signed) `short` variable, `input`. Since the value is outside the range representable in `short`, and since `short` is signed, this results in either an implementation-defined result or an implementation-defined signal being raised.

Change the type of `input` to `unsigned short` and everything will be fine.

Comment: Lots of pretty good answers. This one is pretty good. Apparently, %d is good. Ensuring that I have a type that is capable of storing the number seems the most fundamental thing.

Answer (score 3):

The return type for `str_2_dec()` is `unsigned short` but you are storing the value in a (signed) `short` variable.  You should declare your variables the appropriate type otherwise you will have problems as you have observed.

In this case, you converted `"65535"` to an `unsigned short` which has the bit pattern `FFFF`<sub>Hex</sub>.  That bit pattern was reinterpreted as a (signed) `short` which is the decimal value `-1`.

You should change your `main()` to something like this:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned short input; /* to match the type the function is returning */
    char input_string[6]= "65535";

    input = str_2_dec(input_string, 5);

    printf("Final Value: %hf", input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the variable was declared unsigned, then the specifier would just work since short values get promoted to ints when passed by means of ellipsis.

Comment: Indeed, this is not the problem. `%d` is perfectly valid for printing `unsigned short` or `short`, assuming `short` is strictly narrower than `int`.

Comment: @K-ballo: Except on systems where `sizeof(short) == sizeof(int)`, but behavior is still guaranteed correct on such systems for values in the range `0..INT_MAX`.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: In systems where `sizeof(short) == sizeof(int)` the value would still be printed the same for the `%d` specifier, thats why its important that he declares input as `unsigned short`.

Comment: @K-ballo: Yeah there was a number of issues with the code, I just focused on the wrong part.  Unfortunately when some people say that a function returns something, they mean they printed something and I focused on that.  I (incorrectly) assumed that the other variable types were all appropriate.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: Would you consider removing the misleading information that the format specifier is wrong?

Comment: @K-ballo: Actually I still stand by what I said about the wrong specifier.  It was still wrong.  But I did initially miss the main problem with the code (which I have now addressed).

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: There is nothing wrong in printing a short as a signed decimal integer, sorry but that's my -1.

Comment: @K-ballo: Ah, you know what, I see what you are saying now.  Sorry, it's been a long day for me and my head is just thinking very slowly right now.  That part of my post really was irrelevant so it is now removed.  Can I bribe you to remove that downvote if I upvote you?  (I'll still upvote you either way :))

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: There, no need to downvote once the misinformation was removed.

Answer (score 1):

You mean that is printing index as it was a `(signed) short` here?

```
short input;
...
printf("Final Value: %d", input);
```

**Update:** Since the hint doesn't seem to be catching, I will be more direct: Your declaration of input should be `unsigned short input;`.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the wrong format specifier in printf.  try using `%u` instead of `%d`

Answer (score -1):

The problem isn't with the function but with how you are printing the return value.

```
printf("Final Value: %d", input);
```

The `%d` is place-holder for `int` type, not short.

Use `%hu` instead.

Answer (score -2):

You didn't use the correct format specifier for the

```
short input;
printf("final value=%d\n",input);
```

This makes the difference of your out put.

Comment: Please don't use `u` or `ur` instead of `you` and `your`. Also, please capitalize the first letter of the sentence. Those are some of the reasons your posts get downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for your advice i will definately consider it.